# Is there a reward for completing all challenges in SSBU?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I know there are additional rewards for completing a "page"/"section" of the challenges, but are there any additional rewards for completing *ALL* of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [other boards](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/234547-super-smash-bros-ultimate/77324497) and other answers from the web, it appears that you get nothing for completing all challenges.  Pretty universally considered a strange and annoying omission by the developers.